# Using Dojo with Tapestry 5.4

Tags: dojo, requirejs, tapestry

I am planning to use Dojo toolkit with Tapestry 5.4. I started off with the tapestry quickstart project and tried to include dojo. However, I have been facing a lot of issues w.r.t the new require mechanisms.
- Unknown Type error - require is not a function
- Unable to load the dojo module

webapp Directory structure

```
webapp
   +------- mybootstrap
                 +----------- js (part of tapestry quick start project)
   +------- js (js folder I added for Dojo)
                 +----------- dojo (All dojo files here)
```

Using it with Tapestry 5.3 was pretty simple - including the dojo.js file in the layout component. The same thing does not work in 5.4

I have tried using requirejs data-main attribute, but still stuck with it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I see a JavaScriptModule in Tapestry Jar which includes the require.js and other dependencies.  Somehow it needs to be bypassed. There seems to be  a project https://github.com/adamhenderson/tapestry-dojo  [An attempt to use the Dojo Toolkit as the Infrastructure Provider for Tapestry 5.4] which might be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your dojo files in webapp\js folder.

your folder structure should be like

```
// Folder structure
-webapp
    -js
        -dojo
        -digit
        -dojox
```

Note: Make sure you provide the access to js/* path. So that url : http://localhost:8080/app/js/dojo/dojo.js accessible.

Put a script tag inside your tapestry page (*.tml) and add dojo modules using requireJS using below script,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

setTimeout(

    function() {
        var dojoConfig = {
            async : true
        };

    require.config({
        packages : 
            [ {
                name : 'dojo',
                location : '../js/dojo'
            } ],    
    });

    require(
        [ 'dojo', 'dojo/dom' ],
        function(dojo, dom) {
            console.log(dojo);
            dom.byId("myDiv").innerHTML = "updatedHTML content";
    });

}, 1000);

</script>
```

thats it.